# How to solve "java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be resolved to URL" when trying to add ssl certificate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security

I am trying to add an existing SSL certificate(.cer) to a Spring boot application. Followed the following steps,

Step 1: Converted the existing .cer certificate to .p12 certificate using the below command in keytool of JDK 8.

```
keytool -import -alias cert -file myCertificate.crt -keystore certificate.p12 -storepass password
```

Step 2 : Placed this certificate.p12 that was generated in "resources" folder of the application.

Step 3 : Added the below configuration in "application.properties"

```
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:certificate.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-alias=cert
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.port=8443  
security.require-ssl=true
```

Step 4 : Added the below "SecurityConfig.java" file in application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

Step 5 : Added the below code in "Application.java"

```
@Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }
private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        return connector;
    }
```

After adding all the above code and configuration changes. I am getting the below exception when I start the spring boot application - `Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 'classpath:certificate.p12' Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [certificate.p12] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`. Kindly help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you running the app when it can't find the `certificate.p12` file? Has the file made it from `src/main/resources` into a location where it'll be on the classpath?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson The file is placed in the src/main/resources folder only. But still Iam facing this issue.

Comment: Spring Boot won't be able to find it in `src/main/sources`. Something (your IDE or your build system) needs to copy it to a location that's on the class path. For Maven, that would be in a directory beneath `target` and for Gradle it would be in a directory beneath `build`. Different locations may be used if you're running your application in your IDE. It depends on the IDE and build system you're using.